# Using segue inside custom cell TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create three segues inside my TableViewController in a custom cell and currently it's not working because I can't send the correct "username" throught the second and the third segue.

The second and the third segue are triggered when the user press the UIImageView and a UILabel (which are connected to a TapGestureRecognizer), and in those two segues I have the problem, because the "username" is not updated (it's always the same, the first one in my TableViewController).

What is wrong with my code? I'm going to post some screenshots of my StoryBoard because I don't know where is something wrong...

Here you are my Segue code (the first one is working fine):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSLog(@"RecipeName ==> %@", [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"username"]);

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects:
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"date"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"id"],
                                               [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"imagen"],
                                               nil];
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueprofile"]) {

        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"username"];
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueprofile2"])
    {
        OtherProfileUserViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        destViewController.recipeName = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]] valueForKey:@"username"];
    }
}
```

Here you are my screenshots from my StoryBoard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOvp3.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint, check values you receive from _jsonArray, check indexPath.row

Comment: I checked the value for "indexPathForSelectedRow" and when I press the first segue (the one working) it shows "<NSIndexPath: 0x15e3a5b0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}" but when I press the other two segues it shows (null).

Comment: It means your cell is not selected anymore. Save the index path for selected item before using performSegue and then use it from prepareForSegue.

Comment: Also, the jsonArray contains all the info regarding the entries from my TableViewController so I get every entry.

Comment: How can I do that @Andy, can you show me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add NSIndexPath property in your controller and assign the index path of selected cell to it before you call performSegue.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are using if try to use switch case or try if once and else if for others not sure but try to check it.

Comment: The Segues are triggered correctly, but it seems that they are not sending the same information depending on which one I have pressed. if you need more code I can show you, I think it maybe a different between the first one and the other segues...